# Appending result of function on another field into csv using shell script, awk

Tags: shell, csv, awk, sed, edit

I have a csv file stored as a temporary variable in a shell script (*.sh).

Let's say the data looks like this:

```
Account,Symbol,Price
100,AAPL US,200
102,SPY US,500
```

I want to add a fourth column, "Type", which is the result of a shell function "foobar". Run from the command line or a shell script itself:

```
$ foobar "AAPL US"
"Stock"
$ foobar "SPY US"
"ETF"
```

How do I add this column to my csv, and populate it with calls to foobar which take the second column as an argument? To clarify, this is my ideal result post-script:

```
Account,Symbol,Price,Type
100,AAPL US,200,Common Stock
102,SPY US,500,ETF
```

I see many examples online involving such a column addition using awk, and populating the new column with fixed values, conditional values, mathematical derivations from other columns, etc. - but nothing that calls a function on another field and stores its output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
export -f foobar

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{print $0, "Type"; next} {
   cmd = "foobar \"" $2 "\""; cmd | getline line; close(cmd); 
   print $0, line
}' file.csv
```

```
Account,Symbol,Price,Type
100,AAPL US,200,Common Stock
102,SPY US,500,ETF
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Appended the field into the csv.

Comment: I am getting `sh: 1: foobar: not found`, any idea why and how to make it work? :O

Comment: I created a script that contains some dummy function `foobar() { echo foo; }`, and simply copy pasted your code.

Comment: For some reason even this `foobar() { echo bla;}; export -f foobar; awk 'BEGIN{cmd="foobar"; cmd | getline line; print line}'` doesn't work on my machine. Strange...probably some `awk` compatibility issue?

Comment: I have tested this on BSD as well as gnu awk

Comment: @anubhava `bash: foobar: command not found` ... so strange. I will try to dig a bit deeper into it :) Thanks for assistance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51978440/1745001 for feedback I couldn't fit in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

@anubhavas answer is a good approach so please don't change the accepted answer as I'm only posting this as an answer as it's too big and in need of formatting to fit in a comment.

FWIW I'd write his awk script as:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==1 { type = "Type" }
    NR > 1 {
        cmd  = "foobar \047" $2 "\047"
        type = ((cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "ERROR")
        close(cmd)
    }
    { print $0, type }
' file.csv
```

to:

1. better protect $2 from shell expansion, and
2. protect from silently printing the previous value if/when `cmd | getline` fails, and
3. consolidate the print statements to 1 line so it's easy to change for all output lines if/when necessary

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ echo "Account,Symbol,Price
100,AAPL US,200
102,SPY US,500" | 
awk -F, 'NR>1{cmd="foobar "$2; cmd | getline type} {print $0 FS (NR==1?"Type":type)}'
```

Not sure you need to quote the input to `foobar`

Answer (score 1):

Another way not using `awk`:

```
paste -d, input.csv <({ read; printf "Type\n"; while IFS=, read -r _ s _; do foobar "$s"; done; } < input.csv)
```